# Sybase ASE 15 Aggregate Function for strings

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, sybase, sap-ase, sybase-ase15

I'am findind a way to aggregate strings from differents rows into a single row in sybase ASE 15. Like this:

```
id | Name                    Result: id | Names
-- - ----                            -- - -----
1  | Matt                            1  | Matt, Rocks
1  | Rocks                           2  | Stylus
2  | Stylus
```

Something like FOR XML PATH  in T-SQL.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sybase ASE does not have any string aggregate functions like `list()` or `group_concat()`; and while there is some support for `FOR XML`, it does not include support for the `PATH` option/feature.

Assuming you could have an unknown/variable number of rows to append, your only (ASE 15) T-SQL option would be a cursor-based solution.

If you find yourself working with ASE 16 you could write a user-defined function (UDF) to accomplish the task, eg: [emulate group_concat() in ASE 16](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184241)

Answer (score 1):

**Write below query :-**
select id, cursorfunc(id) from table

**Then create below cursor which is used in above query**
DECLARE ListCurs CURSOR FOR

//Query to fetch the name
select name from table where id=@id

OPEN ListCurs
SELECT @Status = 0
WHILE @Status = 0
BEGIN
FETCH ListCurs INTO @name

```
IF @Status = 0 
BEGIN
   SELECT  @res = CASE WHEN @res IS NULL THEN '' ELSE @res + '& ' END + @name
END
```

END
CLOSE ListCurs
RETURN (@res)

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is a bit old, but I have had the question recently and this would be a possible solution if you assume an upper bound (10 in my example) on the number of names in the list -

```
    select id,
           max(case n
                 when 0 then Name
               end)
         + max(case n
                 when 1 then ','+ Name
               end)
         + max(case n
                 when 2 then ','+ Name
               end)
         + max(case n
                 when 3 then ','+ Name
               end)
         + max(case n
                 when 4 then ','+ Name
               end)
         + max(case n
                 when 5 then ','+ Name
               end)
         + max(case n
                 when 6 then ','+ Name
               end)
         + max(case n
                 when 7 then ','+ Name
               end)
         + max(case n
                 when 8 then ','+ Name
               end)
         + max(case n
                 when 9 then ','+ Name
               end) as Names
from (SELECT t.id,
             t.Name,
             count(t2.Name) as n
      FROM T t
           left join T t2
             on t2.id = t.id
            and t2.Name < t.name
      -- WHERE 
      group by t.id, t.Name) x
group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `Select String_Agg(<Column>, '<Seperator>') From <Table Name>`

Comment: `string_agg()` is not a valid (system) function in SAP(Sybase) ASE

Answer (score -3):

You could try this:

```
select id,list(Names,',' order by id) from TableName a group by id
```

Comment: There is no support for LIST() in Sybase ASE.