# sql query transpose dynamic column to row in sybase or without using any pivot function

Tags: sql, sybase-ase15

My input for table

```
id  value
1    23
1    22
1    24
2    55
2    44
```

my output should be

```
1 23|22|24
2 55|44
```

Please help in providing query which can run in sybase database.

Comment: Is there a maximum number of values for an id?  Why version of Sybase are you using?

Comment: Do you want those values in a single column or in three different columns

Comment: which Sybase db product (ASE? IQ? SQLAnywhere? Advantage?)? SQLAnywhere/IQ have some pivot capabilities that aren't available in ASE ... so at a minimum we need to know which Sybase product (and version would be good to know, too)

Comment: @Gordon -- there is maximum vale for an id, for one id there could be 3 records for other id there could be 4 records.

Comment: @a horse -- values coming single row pipe separated would be preferred else value is single rows with different columns should be a workaround option.

Comment: @markp we are using sybase ase 15.7 version

Comment: ASE does not provide support for `list()`, `group_concant()` nor `FOR XML/PATH`, so you'll need to use a looping construct, eg, create a user-defined function that cursors through the `value`s for a given `id` - keep in mind that you can either a) create a function specific to this table/column set or b) create a (more) generic UDF but then the main query's function call may be a bit more convoluted (see [generic UDF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184241/7366100))

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with `row_number()`, which should be available in your version of Sybase:

```
select id,
       stuff((max(case when seqnum = 1 then '|' + value else '' end) +
              max(case when seqnum = 2 then '|' + value else '' end) +
              max(case when seqnum = 3 then '|' + value else '' end) +
              max(case when seqnum = 4 then '|' + value else '' end)
             ), 1, 1, '') as vals
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by value) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by id;
```

Comment: neither row_number() nor over(partition by works in sybase ASE.