# Creating fuction listagg not returning desired results

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-ase

I am trying to create a function similar to listagg in oracle. though its not returnig the desired data

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MY_STRING_AGG (
    @input VARCHAR(4000),
    @separator CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @output TABLE (result VARCHAR(4000))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @concat VARCHAR(4000)
    SELECT @concat = COALESCE(@concat + @separator, '') + @input
    INSERT INTO @output (result) VALUES (@concat)
    RETURN
END
```

As per this [SO LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477743/listagg-in-sqlserver) they have for sever database except sybase, so my question is there way ot function to column aggreated in one column similat to listagg

Comment: Sybase/SAP ASE does not have anything like `listagg()`, `list()` or `group_concat()`; if you're running ASE 16 you could do something like [this idea for a general purpose user-defined function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184241) but I'll warn ya right now, it's rather convoluted in that you have to send a query as the arg to the function, it works, but it's not pretty; another idea would be something similar to the `sp_autoformat` proc whereby you provide the components for a query (column to 'list', base table, where clauses, order by clause, group by clause), again, doable but messy